# ftplib.error_perm: 553 Could not create file. (Python 2.4.4)

Tags: python, linux, ftp, ftplib

I am writing to the home directory of the user I'm FTPing into, so permissions shouldn't be an issue. FTP works in FileZilla.

I checked the vsftp.conf and made the `local_enable=YES` change

On a *Debian4* system with Python 2.4.4 (I can't upgrade it), I am using this code with ftplib

```
>>> f = ftplib.FTP('address', 'user', 'password')
>>> f.cwd('/home/user/some/dir/')
'250 Directory successfully changed.'
>>> myfile = '/full/path/of/file.txt'
>>> o = open(myfile, 'rb')
>>> f.storbinary('STOR ' + myfile, o)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in ?
File "/usr/lib/python2.4/ftplib.py", line 415, in storbinary
    conn = self.transfercmd(cmd)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/ftplib.py", line 345, in transfercmd
    return self.ntransfercmd(cmd, rest)[0]
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/ftplib.py", line 327, in ntransfercmd
    resp = self.sendcmd(cmd)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/ftplib.py", line 241, in sendcmd
    return self.getresp()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/ftplib.py", line 216, in getresp
    raise error_perm, resp
ftplib.error_perm: 553 Could not create file.
```

Any ideas why it fails?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not writing to a home directory, you are writing to `/full/path/of/file.txt`:

```
myfile = '/full/path/of/file.txt'
...
f.storbinary('STOR ' + myfile, o)
```

You have to use a file name only with the `STOR` command (once the "cwd" is already the correct target path):

```
f.cwd('/home/user/some/dir/')
f.storbinary('STOR file.txt', o)
```

or a correct absolute path for the remote host:

```
f.storbinary('STOR /home/user/some/dir/file.txt', o)
```